# Как сохранить результат ls.str() в виде строки или вектора

Tags: r

Допустим есть таблица

```
myTable <- data.frame(
  a = c("f1", "f2", "f3"),
  b = c(1 , 2 , 3)
)
```

Сохраняю её структуру в объект:

```
struct <- ls.str(myTable)
```

Если я теперь выведу `struct` то получу такой результат:

```
> struct
a :  Factor w/ 3 levels "f1","f2","f3": 1 2 3
b :  num [1:3] 1 2 3
```

Но `struct[1]` покажет просто "a". А как мне сохранить описание структуры и примеры значений в строку?

RStudio пишет, что struct имеет Class `ls_str`, можно его как-то преобразовать в обычный текстовый вектор или список? Варианты с `as.character()` и `paste()` не помогают. Я получаю только имена векторов, без описания их типов. 
При этом сама RStudio показывает эту информацию в панели Enviroment, значит она сама как-то ее выцепляет.

Заранее спасибо, за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#предлгаю вариант перенаправить вывод с консоли в переменную
myTable <- data.frame(
  a = c("f1", "f2", "f3"),
  b = c(1 , 2 , 3)
)

rslt <- capture.output(split = TRUE, {
  ls.str(myTable)
})

# результат:
> rslt[1]
[1] "a :  Factor w/ 3 levels \"f1\",\"f2\",\"f3\": 1 2 3"
> rslt[2]
[1] "b :  num [1:3] 1 2 3"
```

Comment: Да это помогло, огромное спасибо.